# Rails - drop down (select) month / year

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-select

1. How can I create in rails a drop down with all months in it?
2. How do I create a drop down with a list of years beginning from current year and 8 years forward (2012, 2013... 2020)?
   Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For the months:

```
<%= select_month(Date.today) %>
```

(the `Date.today` argument will default it to the current month - use `select_month(1)` to default to January)

For the years:

```
<%= select_year(Date.today, :start_year => Date.today.year, :end_year => 8.years.from_now.years) %>
```

Comment: The answer i was looking for, thanks. Just a small typo on the end. `8.years.from_now.years` should be `8.years.from_now.year`.

Answer (score 8):

```
<%= f.select :month, 1..12 %>

<%= f.select :year, Date.today.year.. 8.years.from_now.year %>
```

Answer (score 4):

A small addition to @alex answer,

By default, if you do

> select_month(Date.today, field_name: 'start')

it will generate select tag with name “date[start]”. If you want it to be something other than date[], add :prefix option, like this:

> select_month(Date.today, field_name: 'start', prefix: 'timer')

This will render select tag with name “timer[start]”.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Diego if you would like the dropdown to display the actual month names instead of the month numbers:

```
<%= f.select :end_date, Date::MONTHNAMES[1..12] %>
```

And then for the year:

```
<%= f.select :end_date, Date.today.year.. 8.years.from_now.year %>
```

Answer (score -1):

this is combinations of select month and year

```
<%= f.month_field(Date.today) :month %>
```

read more: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html